# Xamarin forms iOS local notification buttons

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I need to show action buttons in local notification in iOS. I am getting the notification but there are no action buttons. Could you please guide me what am I doing wrong. 
Here is my code:

```
        var category = new UIMutableUserNotificationCategory();

        var okAction = new UIMutableUserNotificationAction
        {
            Identifier = "ok",
            Destructive = false,
            Title = "OK",
            ActivationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background,
            AuthenticationRequired = false
        };

        var delayAction = new UIMutableUserNotificationAction
        {
            Identifier = "delay",
            Destructive = false,
            Title = "Отложить",
            ActivationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background,
            AuthenticationRequired = false
        };

        var categoryIdentifier = "pills.category";
        category.Identifier = categoryIdentifier;
        category.SetActions(new UIUserNotificationAction[] { delayAction, okAction }, UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal);
        category.SetActions(new UIUserNotificationAction[] { delayAction, okAction }, UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default);

        var categories = new NSSet(new NSObject[] {category});

        var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories
        );
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings);


        var next = new TimeSpan(start.Ticks);

        var count = Math.Round(24.0 / interval.TotalHours);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var notification = new UILocalNotification
            {
                AlertAction = title,
                AlertBody = text,
                SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName,
                ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0,
                FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(next.TotalSeconds),
                RepeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day,
                Category = categoryIdentifier
            };
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);

            next = next.Add(interval);
        }
    }
```

P.S. I am using iOS 11 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swipe down to see the buttons.

The following gif demonstrates **How to operate in `Background` and `Lock Screen`**

[image]